# ListView in a Row Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

What I want to achieve is to have a static Container in the left half and a scroll-able list of items on the right half of the screen:

```
|----------------------|
|           |          |
| Container | ListView |
|           |          |
|----------------------|
```

It is for a desktop app, so I like this layout. My implementation: (appStatWidgets is a list of containers with text)

```
                          Row(
                              children: [
                            Container(height: 400, width: 400, color: Colors.green),
                            Expanded(
                              child: ListView(
                                children: appStatWidgets,
                              ),
                            )
                          ]),
```

But if i do this, the ListView is invisible and I get:

`Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.`

But I thought, that
Expanded would fix that.

What works is putting SizedBox instead of Expanded, but that gives me static size and I would like it to be flexible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `shrinkwrap: true` in your list view parameters, to prevent it from having unbound heights.

And for your Sized box to take half the height for example, use mediaQuery to define the height.
i.e

`SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.50)` This will set it's height to 50% of the screen.

and for `ListView(physics`, use `physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()`.

Comment: If i do shrinkwrap: true the ListView is visible, but overflows bottom. Also it isn't scrollable

Comment: Keep it inside the exapanded box, and wha'ts overflowing is perhaps the elements inside the ListView. If `appStatWidgets` Has columns inside it or something like that that it's children aren'tmanaged, but it's not the listView it'self. For scrolling, set he parameter in listview `physics:  AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
  Row(
                          children: [
                        Container(height: 400, width: 400, color: Colors.green),
                        Expanded(
                          child:SizedBox(
                             width:100,
                             heigth:100,
                          child:ListView(
                            children: appStatWidgets,
                          ),
                              )
                        )
                      ]),
```

Like this

Answer (score 1):

For a listview in a row, make sure you set the scroll direction to  `Axis.horizontal` and one more thing make sure you provide your listview a vertical bound, so put it in a container with height only.

Comment: Okay, so I put it in a container with a height. It works but do you know of any way, to make the container have 100% height of its parent? (in html terms)

Comment: ```Mediaquery.of(context).size.height``` as height of container

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the listview with sized box and provide width and height

Comment: That works, but what if I want it to take up half of the screen. I cannot use static width with SizedBox with that.

Comment: you can do that provide row main axis alignment then that can help you